# how to get GetItemCheckState in SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a checkBoxList that every time i check/uncheck an item it will sort down/up so the unchecked items will be on top and checked will be on the bottom. for this i created an event checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged. my question is how can I check what the selected it, I get an exeption. I'm assuming this is because it is changing while i am checking to see what the current state is

here is my code:

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = checkedListBox1.Items;
        List<string> checkedList = new List<string>();
        List<string> uncheckedList = new List<string>();
        int selected = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        string state = checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(selected)).ToString();
        //error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
        //Additional information: InvalidArgument = Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
        if (state == "Checked")
            uncheckedList.Add(selected.ToString());
        else
            checkedList.Add(selected.ToString());

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            int index = checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item);
            if (index != selected)
            {
                state = checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(item)).ToString();
                if (state == "Checked")
                    checkedList.Add(item.ToString());
                else
                    uncheckedList.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception.. you need to tell us we are not in the business of playing the guessing game..

Comment: [`ItemCheck`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx) event sounds more appropriate.

Comment: Is there more code?  Because your two lists are only local to that method.

Comment: Be aware of *The check state is not updated until after the `ItemCheck` event occurs.*

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried ItemCheck event. the problem with that was that it also goes into that event when the checkBoxList loads for the first time.

Comment: You can block it during the load with flag or detaching the event handler before the operation and reattaching after. All those little tricks, you know :)